# replacement for "as they are getting older"

Tags: synonyms

I am writing a formal essay and I would like to know a formal synonymical pharse or an equivalent replacement for the structure "as they are getting older".
Can somebody can also come with a consistent formal expression for the word as with the meaning from above?

Comment: synonym phrase. As they become older. get older is become older.

Comment: Isn't grow old more suitable? Anyway, what about that informal "as"?

Comment: No, grow older and become older are the same thing.

Comment: What about "as they age"?